# How to connect an LED indicator to a circuit?

Tags: led, switches

I would like to know how can i add a safety switch with an LED indicator to a circuit , so that if the safety switch is on then the LED lights , and when i want to use the device , all what i have to do is to press the normally-open switch.

I have attached this schematic and im not sure if it will work correctly  ,as i am a very beginner in electronics

Thanks

[image]

Comment: What is your device that you are trying to power?  What is operational voltage? Current?  What switches are you using?  Power ratings, current ratings, voltage ratings?

Comment: the inputs of the device require the following :                      Input voltage: DC3.7-7.4V
Input Current: 2A-5A

Comment: how can i size the switches please?

Comment: it's going to be a project for an arc generator

Comment: you better add reverse diode to LEd for protection and use twisted pairs for long connections. Normally power switches need 10% of rated current to maintain clean contacts free of oxide. <2A rated gold plated contacts are better. but if planning to create an arc , be prepared to read about EMI problems.

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing anything about your voltage source or load current, it's hard to suggest an accurate design...

But yes, you have the general idea correct.

Of course, you must Size the led resistor for your voltage and led current, size the switches to the voltage and load current.

Comment: With a "safety switch" involved, I'm wondering about rocket launchers here.

Comment: the inputs of the device require the following :                      Input voltage: DC3.7-7.4V
Input Current: 2A-5A                                                                                     how can i size the switches please?

Comment: it's going to be a project for an arc generator

Comment: @malken use a switch that can do 12V at 6 or more Amps, DC. if it's only rated for AC then it's a problem. Then again, it may be easier to use a switch on the ac outlet.